# Elixir upcase only first letter of a word

Tags: string, elixir

I've got a string that I need to only upcase the first letter. I also need to preserve the case of any subsequent letters. At first I thought:

```
String.capitalize("hyperText")
```

would do the trick. But in addition to fixing the first letter, it downcases the rest of the letters. What I need to end up with is "HyperText". My initial pass at this is:

```
<<letter :: utf8, rest :: binary>> = word
upcased_first_letter = List.to_string([letter])
|> String.upcase()

upcased_first_letter <> rest
```

This works perfectly but it really seems like a lot of verbosity and a lot of work as well. I keep feeling like there's a better way. I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: I would recommend https://github.com/sobolevn/recase

Comment: interesting, thanks :) unfortunately I'm doing an exercism exercise and need to write it all w/o libraries, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`with/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#with/1) to keep it to a single expression, and you can avoid `List.to_string` by using the `<<>>` operator again on the resulting codepoint:

```elixir
with <<first::utf8, rest::binary>> <- "hyperText", do: String.upcase(<<first::utf8>>) <> rest
```

Or put it in a function:

```elixir
def upcaseFirst(<<first::utf8, rest::binary>>), do: String.upcase(<<first::utf8>>) <> rest
```

Comment: actually I have a question about this. I hadn't made the connection that if I passed in the codepoint to upcase as <<first::utf8>> it would treat it as a string.  `String.upcase(first)` barfs but `String.upcase(<<first::utf8>>)`  works. Can anyone point me at a place where I can find an explanation of this (or even shove and explanation in here)?

Comment: [`<<>>/1-types`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%3C%3C%3E%3E/1-types). `first` is matched as an integer. `<<first::utf8>>` means "`first` is an integer that represents the codepoint of the character in the utf8-encoded binary". You can't upcase an integer, but using the binary syntax converts it back to a utf-8-encoded string, which you can then upcase.

Answer (score 4):

One method:

```
iex(10)> Macro.camelize("hyperText")
"HyperText"
```

This *might* be more UTF-8 compatible? Not sure how many letters are multiple codepoints, but this seems a little safer than assuming how many bytes a letter is going to be.

```
iex(6)> with [first | rest] <- String.codepoints("βool") do
...(6)> [String.capitalize(first) | rest] |> Enum.join()
...(6)> end
"Βool"
iex(7)> with [first | rest] <- String.codepoints("ool") do
...(7)> [String.capitalize(first) | rest] |> Enum.join()
...(7)> end
"ool"
iex(8)>
```

Comment: From the docs for Macro.camelize: "Do not use it as a general mechanism for
camelizing strings as it does not support Unicode or characters that are not
valid in Elixir identifiers".

Comment: May be worth pointing out: the OP's method of using `<<letter :: utf8>>` is unicode safe and doesn't make any assumptions about the number of bytes in a character.

Comment: yeah, this won't work for me...BUT (and it's a big butt), I really never even thought of this approach so I appreciate the answer anyway. When I stop and think about it, it's so straight forward.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just upcasing the English alphabet, you could do an easy guard clause on your match. An anonymous function example, though named or a `with` or something would work too:

```rb
iex> cap_first = fn
...>   <<first, rest::binary>> when first in ?a..?z -> <<first - 32, rest::binary>>
...>   string -> string
...> end
iex> cap_first.("hyperText")
"HyperText"
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Adam Millerchip's answer,

```
with <<first::binary-size(1), rest::binary>> <- "my string", do: String.upcase(first) <> rest
```